# How do I display SignalR messages on a client sent from an Asp.Net Core 2.1 MVC Web controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr

I have an Asp.Net Core 2.1, MVC, C# Web application in Visual Studio 2017 15.7.5.
Using SignalR 1.0.2.

One menu option gathers product information and displays a Product List.  All of the code is shown at the end of this post.

It starts out by showing the AccessToken.cshtml screen.  From there, I click the "Get Products" button and it does the product gathering in the ProductsController\GetProducts method and shows the Products.cshtml screen.

The problem I am having is that this line in the GetProducts method:

```
await this._hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", productCount.ToString() + " Model code: " + chvproduct.model_code, "  Product ID: " + chvproduct.product_id.ToString());
```

is not showing on the AccessToken screen.

I can get the hub messages to display on the AccessToken screen by activating the GetProducts method in a different way from the AccessToken.cshtml view and I can show that if anyone would like to see it.  The problem with that, is it displays the hub messages OK on the AccessToken screen, but it never displays the Products List(Products.cshtml).

Here is all my code:

**Startup.cs**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ChinavasionAPI.Data;
using ChinavasionAPI.Hubs;

namespace ChinavasionAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
               // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache.
               services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

               services.AddSession(options =>
               {
                    // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
                    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
               });

               services.AddRouting();

               services.AddSignalR();
               services.AddMvc();

            services.AddDbContext<ChinavasionAPIContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ChinavasionAPIContext")));
          }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
               routes.MapHub<ChvHub>("/chvHub");
            });

               app.UseMvc(routes =>
               {
                 routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "token",
                    template: "token",
                    defaults: new { controller = "API", action = "GetAccessToken" });

                 routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "GetProducts",
                    template: "products",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "GetProducts" });

                 routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

               });
        }
    }
}
```

**ChvHub.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace  ChinavasionAPI.Hubs
{
     public class ChvHub : Hub
     {
          public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
          {
               await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
          }
     }
}
```

**chat.js**

```js
// The following sample code uses modern ECMAScript 6 features 
// that aren't supported in Internet Explorer 11.
// To convert the sample for environments that do not support ECMAScript 6, 
// such as Internet Explorer 11, use a transpiler such as 
// Babel at http://babeljs.io/. 
//
// See Es5-chat.js for a Babel transpiled version of the following code:

const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
     .withUrl("/chvHub")
     .build();

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) => {
     const msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
     const encodedMsg = user + msg;
     const li = document.createElement("li");
     li.textContent = encodedMsg;
     document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
});

connection.start().catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", event => {
     const user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
     const message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
     connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
     event.preventDefault();
});

document.getElementById("get-products-button").addEventListener("click", event => {
     connection.invoke("SendMessage", "test User", "Test message").catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
     event.preventDefault();
});
```

**AccessToken.cshtml**

```html
@model ChinavasionAPI.Models.AccessModel
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions

@{
     ViewData["Title"] = "Access Token";
}

@section Scripts {
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="~/lib/signalr/signalr.js"></script>
     <script src="~/js/chat.js"></script>
}

<div>
     <h2>Access Data</h2>
     @using (Html.BeginRouteForm("Submit", FormMethod.Post))
     {
          <table>
               <tr>
                    <td>
                         <label for="serverUrl">Server url: </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <input name="serverUrl" type="text" id="serverUrl" value="@Model.UserAccessModel.ServerUrl" style="width:400px" />
                    </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td>
                         <label for="clientId">Client Id: </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <input name="clientId" type="text" id="clientId" value="@Model.UserAccessModel.ClientId" style="width:400px" />
                    </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td>
                         <label for="clientSecret">Client Secret: </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <input name="clientSecret" type="text" id="clientSecret" value="@Model.UserAccessModel.ClientSecret" style="width:400px" />
                    </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td>
                         <label for="redirectUrl">Redirect Url: </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <input name="redirectUrl" type="text" id="redirectUrl" readonly="readonly" value="@Model.UserAccessModel.RedirectUrl" style="width:400px" />
                    </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                         <br />
                         <input type="submit" value="Get Access Token" />
                         <button type="button" id="refresh-token-button">Refresh Access Token</button>
                    </td>
               </tr>
          </table>
     }
</div>

<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
          <form asp-controller="Products" asp-action="GetProducts" method="get">
               <div class="col-6">&nbsp;</div>
               <div class="col-6">
                    <ul id="messagesList"></ul>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" id="get-products-button" value="Get Products" class="btn btn-default" />
               </div>
          </form>
     </div>
</div>
```

**ProductsController.cs**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Lakeside.Api.AdapterLibrary;
using ChinavasionAPI.DTOs;
using ChinavasionAPI.Models;
using ChinavasionAPI.Models.CAPIViewModels;
using ChinavasionAPI.Data;
using ChinavasionAPI.Hubs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace ChinavasionAPI.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
          private readonly ChinavasionAPIContext _context;
          private readonly IHubContext<ChvHub> _hubContext;

          public ProductsController(ChinavasionAPIContext context, IHubContext<ChvHub> hubcontext)
          {
               _context = context;
               _hubContext = hubcontext;
          }

          public async Task<IActionResult> GetProducts()
          {
                    var model = new AccessModel();
                    model.UserAccessModel = _context.UserAccessModels.Single(a => a.ID == 1);

                    var accessToken = (model.UserAccessModel.AccessToken ?? TempData["accessToken"]).ToString();
                    var serverUrl = (model.UserAccessModel.ServerUrl ?? TempData["serverUrl"]).ToString();

                    var nopApiClient = new ApiClient(accessToken, serverUrl);
                    MultipleProductModel multipleProductModel = new MultipleProductModel();
                    List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();

                    string jsonUrl = $"/api/products?limit=10&fields=id,sku,name,images,categories";
                    object productsData = nopApiClient.Get(jsonUrl);

                    var productsRootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductsRootObject>(productsData.ToString());

                    var products = productsRootObject.Products.Where(
                         product => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(product.Name));

                    multipleProductModel.MProductsApi = productsRootObject.Products;

                    int productCount = 0;
                    int? setupID = 1;

                    if (setupID == null)
                    {
                         return NotFound();
                    }

                    var setup = await _context.Setups.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == setupID);
                    if (setup == null)
                    {
                         return NotFound();
                    }

                    serverUrl = setup.ServerUrl;
                    string serverKey = setup.Key;
                    string queryCall = "api/getProductDetails.php";
                    string parameterName = "model_code";
                    multipleProductModel.MProducts.Clear();
                    var productsService = new Service.ProductService();

                    foreach (ProductApi nopProduct in products)
                    {
                         Product chvproduct = (await productsService.GetProductBySkuAPIAsync(serverUrl, serverKey, queryCall, parameterName, nopProduct.Sku));
                         if (chvproduct == null)
                         {
                              multipleProductModel.MProducts.Add(new Product { product_id = 0, model_code = "Not on file" });
                         }
                         else
                         {
                              multipleProductModel.MProducts.Add(chvproduct);
                         }
                         productCount += 1;
                         await this._hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", productCount.ToString() + " Model code: " + chvproduct.model_code, "  Product ID: " + chvproduct.product_id.ToString());
                    }

                    var result =
                        from c in multipleProductModel.MProductsApi
                        join p in multipleProductModel.MProducts on c.Sku equals p.model_code into ps
                        from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new ProductViewModel
                        {
                             Id = c.Id,
                             Sku = c.Sku,
                             Categories = c.Categories,
                             product_id = p?.product_id != null ? p.product_id : 99999,
                             model_code = p?.model_code != null ? p.model_code : "",
                        };

                    return View("~/Views/API/Products.cshtml", result.ToList());
          }
    }
}
```

```
**Added 07/17/2018 at 4:03PM EDST**
I noticed that when I look at the console output for this application when it displays the AccessToken.cshtml screen:

    >  [Show/hide message details.] POST
    http://localhost:64370/API/Process
    [HTTP/1.1 302 Found 6ms]
    [Show/hide message details.] GET
    http://www.lakesideos.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=bdcc05db-75e5-40f7-bb0d-2f8929025329&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a64370%2ftoken&response_type=code&state=e1bf9161-c8e4-4af5-a47f-179daa007e4b
    [HTTP/1.1 302 Found 653ms]
    [Show/hide message details.] GET
    http://localhost:64370/token?code=c3b64ab9a91a157c6532e06cbcac8136bb0afb0ba2d477cecf946edecb267643&scope=nop_api%20offline_access&state=e1bf9161-c8e4-4af5-a47f-179daa007e4b
    [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 491ms]
    [Show/hide message details.] GET
    http://localhost:64370/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
    [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
    [Show/hide message details.] GET
    http://localhost:64370/css/site.css
    [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
    [Show/hide message details.] GET
    http://localhost:64370/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js
    [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
    [Show/hide message details.] GET
    http://localhost:64370/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
    [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
    [Show/hide message details.] GET
    http://localhost:64370/js/site.js?v=ji3-IxbEzYWjzzLCGkF1KDjrT2jLbbrSYXw-AhMPNIA
    [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
    [Show/hide message details.] GET
    http://localhost:64370/lib/signalr/signalr.js
    [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
    [Show/hide message details.] GET
    http://localhost:64370/js/chat.js
    [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
    [Show/hide message details.] GET
    https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js
    [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]
    Information: Normalizing '/chvHub' to 'http://localhost:64370/chvHub'. Utils.ts:165:20
    [Show/hide message details.] XHRPOST
    http://localhost:64370/chvHub/negotiate
    [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 4ms]
    [Show/hide message details.] GET
    http://localhost:64370/chvHub?id=yofwGxiN9fXlPwMRBHYcLw
    [HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols 74ms]
    Information: WebSocket connected to ws://localhost:64370/chvHub?id=yofwGxiN9fXlPwMRBHYcLw

I don't know much about this output, but it seems to show, in the last four lines, that the SignalR connection is made.

When I click the "Get Products" button, it shows this:

> Information: Connection disconnected. signalr.js:1887:21
[Show/hide message details.] GET
http://localhost:64370/products
 [Show/hide message details.] GET
http://localhost:64370/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
[Show/hide message details.] GET
http://localhost:64370/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
[Show/hide message details.] GET
http://localhost:64370/js/site.js?v=ji3-IxbEzYWjzzLCGkF1KDjrT2jLbbrSYXw-AhMPNIA
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
[Show/hide message details.] GET
http://localhost:64370/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
[Show/hide message details.] GET
http://localhost:64370/css/site.css
```

It shows the SignalR being disconnected and then the Products List screen.

Can anyone explain why It would disconnect when the GetProducts method is executed?

**Added this on 07/18/2018 7:15PM EDST**

I added this to my chat.js file:

```js
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
     if ($.connection.hub.lastError) { alert("Disconnected. Reason: " + $.connection.hub.lastError.message); }
});
```

I used the Mozilla developer tools to stop on that statement and ran my application.  It never stopped there.  I also, put a stop on this line:

```js
connection.start().catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
```

And it did stop there.

Can anyone explain why it would stop on the connection.start, but not stop on the  connection.hub.disconnected line.

Thanks,
Tony

**Added this on 07/20/2018 8:35AM EDST**

I put this coding into my ChvHub.cs file:

```
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
      {
           await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", Context.User.Identity.Name, " has joined");
      }

  public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
      {
           await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", Context.User.Identity.Name, "left");
      }
```

Using the Visual Studio debugger, I put breakpoints on the two override methods in the ChvHub class and another breakpoint on the first line of the GetProducts method.

When I run my application in the Debug Mode and use the menu option to show the AccessToken.cshtml screen, the line in the OnConnectionAsync override method is hit.  Once, I click the Get Products button, the line in the OnDisconnectedAsyncoverride method is hit, F5 and then it hits the first line of the GetProducts method.

So, for some reason the hub connection is terminating before it even gets to the GetProducts method.  Why?

Comment: I'm trying to add some debugging information, but it won't show it the way I enter it.  I don't know what to do about that.

Comment: try to minimize your code with only the effecting parts.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane I'm not sure I understand.  Can you be more specific about what code you are referring to?